# React Material UI error <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to put a **react-bootstrap carousel** in each **React material-UI tab**.
And I got the error `Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>`. Where should I fix?

I have copy all [my codes on github](https://gist.github.com/chelsey0527/5bdf7eae28c1388afea8fc1953f5ada4), due to the length restrict of stackoverflow.

Comment: Looks like you are rendering a div tag inside a paragraph tag. Is `p` an actual prop of the `Box` component? You have to make sure that the component does not render divs inside a paragraph tag.

Comment: @iismaell seems like using Box with p={3} will make react consider it as a new <div> with <p> wrapped, much thanks ! I will try to change the data type of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem,kept looking for root p but there was none. Then i had the idea to look up tabPanel function and inside the box there was

```
<Typography>{children}</Typography>
```

just change the tag from typography to a div or an empty div and the warning will disappear

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the attribute

```
component={span}
```

In material UI components that is nested.